# Make judgement and give reminder based on date (failed)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to judge whether today's date is later than any date specified in a column of a worksheet everytime the workbook is opened to decide whether will give user a reminder. I use debug.print to make sure the condition I set was correct but there was no reminder popped out everytime I open the file. Could anyone point out where did I make the mistake? Thanks.

I used cdbl to convert date to double and compare between today and the date in the column. If anyone of them is earlier than today it will give user a reminder.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer

Count = 0

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gun Inventory")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        If Int(CDbl(Date)) > Int(CDbl(.Cells(i, "J").Value)) Or Int(CDbl(Date)) = Int(CDbl(.Cells(i, "J").Value)) Then
        .Cells(i, "I") = "Needs Test"
        Count = Count + 1
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

If Count <> 0 Then MsgBox "You have guns needs check ASAP. Please review 'gun inventory' tab to see which gun it is."

End With

End Sub
```

I expect there should be a reminder but there is nothing. Not even an error, which is weird.

Comment: Does your Workbook immediately open the userform? If not you need to put that code into the Workbook open event not userform initialize

Comment: I think the problem is with the `Else: Exit Sub` line. Execution stops the first time the date is less than the cell, even when there are more cells to check.

Comment: @Warcupine yes it does. I did try put it in workbook open but it doesn't work

Comment: Is cnt supposed to count?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute that portion of code when the workbook is opened you should use:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Insert code here
End Sub
```

Or use Workbook_Open() but you will have to add it in ThisWorkbook class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but neither of the solution you provided works

Comment: Other problem seems to be the Else statement where you are exiting the Sub, i would suggest to move it to the second conditional that you are using for the count.